# How can I block my urls through the browser searcher in my Django app?

Tags: html, django, security, django-forms, django-templates

So I´m developing an app in Django and I wanted to add a little bit of security to it.

Currently I can access to any URL through the browser searcher so my aim is to block the urls of my app so I can only access them by starting from my main page in which I have two buttons of login and register. I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

my main page paginaPrincipal.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block titulo %} PAGINA PRINCIPAL {% endblock %}

{%block contenido %}

<p class="pPrincipal">Tengo una cuenta</p>
<p><a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="button">Iniciar Sesion</a></p>
<p class="pPrincipal">No tengo una cuenta</p>
<p><a href="{% url 'registro_usuario' %}" class="button">Registrarse</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you mean only allowing login user to visit this page, you can try the [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator on the view to this page, like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def paginaPrincipalView(request):
    ...
```